# Add class to radio's label when selected, and remove the class when it isn't?

Tags: jquery

My HTML has radio buttons inside their labels. I need to add a class to this label when the radio is selected, and remove the class when it is not.

My code below adds the class when the radio is selected but doesn't remove it when its unselected.

http://jsfiddle.net/UJM6G/

```
<div class="form-input radios"> <div class="form-radios form-element-type-radios"><div class="form-form-element-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-item-radio">
<div class="form-input radio"> <label class="option" for="edit-vehicle-owner-1"><input type="radio" name="vehicle_owner" value="1" class="form-radio form-element-type-radios"> Yes</label>
</div><div class="form-error"></div></div>
</div><div class="form-form-element-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-item-radio">
<div class="form-input radio"> <label class="option" for="edit-vehicle-owner-0"><input type="radio" value="0" class="form-radio form-element-type-radios"> No</label>
</div><div class="form-error"></div></div>
</div></div>
</div>

  $('.form-element-type-radios').click(function(){
    if ( $('input.form-radio').is(':checked') ) {
      $(this).parent('label').addClass('checked');
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent('label').removeClass('checked');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.change()` event

```
$('input.form-radio').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('input.form-radio').parent('label').removeClass('checked')
        $(this).parent('label').addClass('checked');
    }
}).change();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UJM6G/14/)

Comment: The issue with this solution is that if the radio is already selected on page load then the class isn't added.

Comment: @jdln, I have updated answer, Hope this solves your problem. See the updated demo. Just added `checked` attribute to `Yes` radio

Answer (score 0):

Try doing that for all buttons using each function

```
$('.form-element-type-radios').click(function(){
    $('input.form-radio').each(function(){
      $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).parent('label').addClass('checked') : $(this).parent('label').removeClass('checked');
        })
  });
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UJM6G/13/)